# Python Google Sheets API Not Setting Values (no error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets

I have this code (below) to check a Google Sheet for a random value, return it, and set another value. All the heavy lifting of checking the sheet works, the only issue is the `update` method. Using debugging, I see that it does make it to the update method, it just doesn't work. There is no error message. Also, scopes are set to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets. Thanks in advance!

```py
def getitem(ctxuid):
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists("token.json"):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
          creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
          flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
              "credentials.json", SCOPES
          )
          creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open("token.json", "w") as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds)

        # Call the Sheets API
        sheet = service.spreadsheets()
        result = (
            sheet.values()
            .get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range="Sheet1!A2:C101")
            .execute()
        )
        values = result.get("values", [])
        available = []
        for i in range(len(values)):
            if values[i][2] == "Available":
                available.append(values[i])
        choice = random.choice(range(len(available)))
        if ctxuid in calamity_allowSheetUpdate:
            cal_vals = (
                #(available[choice][0],available[choice][1], 'test')
                "ASHOFHSAOFOHISA"
                )
            cal_vals_rangeBody = {
            'majorDimension': "ROWS",
            'values': cal_vals
            }
            sheet.values().update(
                spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,range=f"Sheet1!A{values.index(available[choice])+2}",valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",body=cal_vals_rangeBody) #CHECK FOR AVAILABLE VALUE IN REGULAR VALUES, THEN UPDATE TO "Unavailable" IN RED
            # print(f"Sheet1!A{values.index(available[choice])+2}",cal_vals_rangeBody)
        return f"### The shaboingery gods have chosen...\n# {available[choice][0]}\n## {available[choice][1]}"
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: the necessary files, `credentials.json` and `token.json` are present and correct.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And, what is `calamity_allowSheetUpdate` in your showing script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about this. I just forgot to run `.execute()` on it

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put `.execute()` after my update method.